# write data in txt file vertically column by column using tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to write a data in a .txt file vertically column by column like :

```
{INST 1410 0x40011B48 0xC2006228 0x00000000 0 0 0} 

{INST 1422 0x40011B4C 0x80A06000 0x00000000 0 0 0}

{INST 1428 0x40011B50 0x02800005 0x00000000 0 0 0} 

{INST 1429 0x40011B54 0x84102000 0x00000000 0 0 0} 

{INST 1430 0x40011B64 0x81C7E008 0x40011B64 0 0 0}
```

but after running below mentioned code:

```
#!/bin/env tcl


set allexes [glob -directory "wcet_executable" -- "bs.exe"]

    foreach f $allexes {
        set puts "$f"
        set data [open "wcet_executable/executables_filenames.txt" a+]
        puts  $data "$f"
        load "$f"
        run
        set instructions [inst 5000]        
         puts   $data $instructions

    close $data

}
```

I GOT : all executions in one line I am new in tcl I think i need to do something with puts, but don't know what, please help if someone knows.

```
{INST 1410 0x40011B48 0xC2006228 0x00000000 0 0 0} {INST 1422 0x40011B4C 0x80A06000 0x00000000 0 0 0} {INST 1428 0x40011B50 0x02800005 0x00000000 0 0 0} {INST 1429 0x40011B54 0x84102000 0x00000000 0 0 0} {INST 1430 0x40011B64 0x81C7E008 0x40011B64 0 0 0} {INST 1441 0x40011B68 0x91E80002 0x00000000 0 0 0}
```

Comment: Does [inst] return a list?

Comment: As Brad pointed out, it seems that the variable `instructions` is a list of list. Use `foreach elem $instructions { puts $data $elem }` to print them in separate line.

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you?

```
#!/bin/env tcl

set f wcet_executable/bs.exe
set data [open wcet_executable/executables_filenames.txt a+]
puts $data $f
load $f
run
puts $data [join [inst 5000] \n]
close $data
```

If you want to do this for multiple `.exe` files and not just the file named "bs.exe":

```
set data [open wcet_executable/executables_filenames.txt a+]
foreach f [glob -dir wcet_executable *.exe] {
    puts $data $f
    load $f
    run
    puts $data [join [inst 5000] \n]
}
close $data
```

**List output**

Donal Fellows suggested using

```
puts $data [join [inst 5000] \n]
```

which is indeed the most natural solution. If you `puts` a list, the string representation in all its braced glory gets printed. If you `join` the list first, you get the contents of the list in text form, and you can also add some formatting like newlines between elements.

A variation on this is to use Tcllib:

```
package require fileutil
set file wcet_executable/executables_filenames.txt
::fileutil::appendToFile $file [join [inst 5000] \n]
```

In my original answer, I used `foreach`:

```
foreach instruction [inst 5000] {
    puts $data $instruction
}
```

This construct is in general a good way to deal with a list: take each element in turn and do something with it. In this case it's not as good. There's no point in dealing with elements individually when `join` can transform the list as a whole. Also, one thing you really want to do is keep down the number of calls to `puts`: this solution is a couple of orders of magnitude slower than the `join`/`puts` solution.

The lesson for me here is: don't dumb down code in examples. Simple and practical is better than misguidedly educational. I forget that sometimes.

Documentation: [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm), [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [glob](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [load](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/load.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: What about `puts $data [join [inst 5000] \n]`?

Comment: That's much better, but possibly less clear for a newbie. Maybe.